# What is the difference between "stochastic" heat equation and just heat equation?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, sde, pde, heat

I am trying to understand the difference between the "stochastic" heat equation and the heat equation. Will i be wrong to say the stochastic heat equation is just the heat equationg with the white noise term...?

Comment: You would get more results if you search the more general term- stochastic partial differential equations. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_partial_differential_equation

Comment: Yes, there is an additional noise term, and that makes it a much different (and more difficult) type of equation.